# spring data fetch mapped object in order

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, one-to-many

We have Spring Boot 2.x, Spring Data and PostgreSQL as database.

In our application we have `Driver` class as below

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Driver {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String licenseNo;
}
```

Now a car can be driven by many drivers. So we have `Car` class as below.

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Car {
    private String id;
    private String number;
    private String registrationNumber;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Driver> drivers;
}
```

Whenever we fetch `drivers` from `car` object we get drivers not ordered by `id` in ascending, seems like it orders by `name` or `id` in descending order.

Is there any way in JPA where we can specify the default order by when we map.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi，you add a annotation in drivers field.

show code.

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Car {
    private String id;
    private String number;
    private String registrationNumber;

    @javax.persistence.OrderBy("id ASC")
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Driver> drivers;
}
```

order option`s 'ASC' 'DESC',default is ASC

exsmple:

```
@javax.persistence.OrderBy("id")

@javax.persistence.OrderBy("name")
```

or:

```
@javax.persistence.OrderBy("id DESC")

@javax.persistence.OrderBy("name  DESC")
```